# Files Prompts for Credentials When 'Save As' is Selected

Tags: credentials, save

I have an issue I need assistance with. The scenario:

- User (Site Owner) goes to Library and attempts to open file as Read Only and hits OK as shown below:

[image]

- Once user is done with edits they Save As show below:

[image]

- When Save As is selected it prompts the user for credentials (ie username and password)

[image]

It only happens on this site and the problem here is that when user enters their credentials it loops back and asks for credentials again and does not allow user to proceed to Save As. In addition, this problem is intermittent. What I mean is that, sometimes when user follows the same steps above and selects Save As it does not prompt user for credentials and functions normally. Lastly, I (Farm Admin) can't seem to reproduce the error. I don't think this is permissions issue as it sometimes works for the user but I just wanted to know if anyone has come across this situation and if so how was it solved? Can someone please assist in this matter?

Comment: how many  web front end you have in farm?

Comment: In farm there are a total of 6 WFEs. Does this have something to do with the issue?